# elasticfence2.2.0 ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

i can not install plugins in elasticsearch-2.2.0，and i have tried to install in several servers. it throws the same excetions: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip

```
sudo bin/plugin install file:///usr/local/src/elasticsearch-2.2.0/elasticfence-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip 

-> Installing from file:/usr/local/src/elasticsearch-2.2.0/elasticfence-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip...
Trying file:/usr/local/src/elasticsearch-2.2.0/elasticfence-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip ...
Downloading .DONE
Verifying file:/usr/local/src/elasticsearch-2.2.0/elasticfence-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip checksums if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip
```

plugin url: https://github.com/elasticfence/elasticsearch-http-user-auth/tree/2.2.x/jar
elasticsearch url: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-2-0

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: did you get anything ??